# Erro ao buscar do valor do campo - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Possuo campo que coloco um valor em um `input` e ele analisa se o valor colocado dentro está dentro do `switch` que está no *JavaScript*. Ele esta dando um o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null.

**O código é o seguinte:**

```
<input type="text" name="" id="nome" value="">
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction() ">Aperte</button>
<p id="pnome"></p>

var fruta = document.getElementById("nome").value;
function myfunction(){
  switch (fruta) {
    case "Laranjas":
      document.write("As laranjas custam R$0,59 o kg");
      break;
    case "Maçãs":
      document.write("As maçãs custam R$1,50 o kg");
      break;
    case "Bananas":
      document.write("As bannas custam R$3,00 o kg");
    default:
    document.write("Desculpe, estamos sem nenhuma " + fruta + ".");
  }
}
document.getElementById("pnome").innerHTML = "nome: " + fruta;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No momento em que o código é executado o elemento ainda não está no `DOM`. Altere o início do seu `script` para:

```
function myfunction(){
    var fruta = document.getElementById("nome").value;
...
```

E o final para:

```
...
    document.getElementById("pnome").innerHTML = "nome: " + fruta;
}
```

Comment: vlw man deu certo. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

O erro acima ocorre pois você tentou acessar a propriedade `value` de um objeto que não existe, se você está buscando um elemento pelo `id` conforme seu exemplo, certifique-se de que esse elemento com este `id` exista no momento em que você tenta acessá-lo.

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

**Obs**.: Adicionei um `if` para verificar se o campo foi preenchido antes do `switch`.

```js
function myfunction(){
  var fruta = document.getElementById("nome").value;

  if(fruta.length == 0){
    document.write("Preencha o nome da fruta.");
  }
  else{
    switch (fruta) {
      case "Laranjas":
        document.write("As laranjas custam R$0,59 o kg");
        break;
      case "Maçãs":
        document.write("As maçãs custam R$1,50 o kg");
        break;
      case "Bananas":
        document.write("As bannas custam R$3,00 o kg");
      default:
      document.write("Desculpe, estamos sem nenhuma " + fruta + ".");
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById("pnome").innerHTML = "nome: " + fruta;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="nome" value="" />
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">
  Aperte
</button>
<p id="pnome"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Além dos problemas citados na resposta do Sorack, outro problema é o `document.write`. Este método substitui o conteúdo da página pela mensagem, logo ao chegar na linha `document.getElementById("pnome").innerHTML`, o elemento `#pnome` não vai mais existir e causará outro erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Logo, você pode criar uma variável `mensagem` que será concatenada e exibida na `div #pnome`:

```js
function myfunction(){
   var fruta = document.getElementById("nome").value;
   
   var mensagem;
   
  switch (fruta) {
    case "Laranjas":
      mensagem = "As laranjas custam R$0,59 o kg";
      break;
    case "Maçãs":
      mensagem = "As maçãs custam R$1,50 o kg";
      break;
    case "Bananas":
      mensagem = "As bannas custam R$3,00 o kg";
    default:
      mensagem = "Desculpe, estamos sem nenhuma " + fruta + ".";
  }
  
   document.getElementById("pnome").innerHTML = mensagem+"<br>nome: " + fruta;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="nome" value="">
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction() ">Aperte</button>
<p id="pnome"></p>
```